# Excel - formula for horizontal data without VBA / Macros?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My data is currently in the following format (I can move it to best suit this purpose but I wanted to know if this was possible first).

```
CELL1   CELL2       CELL3       CELL4       CELLn

ITEM    # MATERIAL  # MATERIAL  # MATERIAL
```

An example of this might be:

```
A       B           C           D           n

Tacos   5 Tortillas 6 Garlic    4 Onions    3 Peppers

Banana  // These cells are empty because Bananas need no ingredients.

Pasta   2 Garlic    3 Sauce
```

I want a formula to go through each unique item in col A, and for each go through all of the ingredients for that item (in columns B -> columns **infinity**). Count each ingredient and how many of each ingredient is needed and then output it in the following way:

```
Torillas    5
Garlic      8
Onions      4
Peppers     3
Sauce       3
```

If this were a programming language, I could do this easily with a few for loops but just using `IF` and `COUNTIF` and `SUM`, I just have no idea where to even begin.

Comment: right up until you said infinite items I would say use an array formula.  Technically speaking if you have infinite ingredients, your calculation will never finish calculating.  And if you are using excel, then your list of ingredients is finite and limited to the number of columns-1.

Comment: What I meant by infinite is keep looking as long as there is data to the right. Meaning an item can have one ingredient, or it can have 50,000.

Comment: This is best suited to a VBA solution.  You can do this with a simple macro.  Although I am curious about your item with 50,000 ingredients and how you would store it given that Excel has only 16,384 columns.

Comment: vba is the best,  with that many possibilities even if someone could come up with an array formula that would work it would crash excel in the number of calculations required to get the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion: Convert the data within the table to 2 vectors, then use a simple pivot table to sum by category.

So first I'll define all the area with the data (`B2:E4`) as a named range `materials`. Then I use a nasty formula to create 2 vectors, one for the item and one or the quantity.

1. For quantity:

```
=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(OFFSET(materials,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($A$9))/COLUMNS(materials)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$9),COLUMNS(materials)),1,1),FIND(" ",OFFSET(materials,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($A$9))/COLUMNS(materials)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$9),COLUMNS(materials)),1,1)))),0,VALUE(LEFT(OFFSET(materials,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($A$9))/COLUMNS(materials)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$9),COLUMNS(materials)),1,1),FIND(" ",OFFSET(materials,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($A$9))/COLUMNS(materials)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($A$9),COLUMNS(materials)),1,1)))))
```

2. For the items:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MID(OFFSET(materials,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($B$9))/COLUMNS(materials)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($B$9),COLUMNS(materials)),1,1),FIND(" ",OFFSET(materials,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($B$9))/COLUMNS(materials)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($B$9),COLUMNS(materials)),1,1))+1,LEN(OFFSET(materials,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($B$9))/COLUMNS(materials)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($B$9),COLUMNS(materials)),1,1)))),"",MID(OFFSET(materials,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($B$9))/COLUMNS(materials)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($B$9),COLUMNS(materials)),1,1),FIND(" ",OFFSET(materials,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($B$9))/COLUMNS(materials)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($B$9),COLUMNS(materials)),1,1))+1,LEN(OFFSET(materials,TRUNC((ROW()-ROW($B$9))/COLUMNS(materials)),MOD(ROW()-ROW($B$9),COLUMNS(materials)),1,1))))
```

You paste it in the first cell of the relevant vector, then change all the cell references (all the `$A$9`, and `$B$9`) to the cell where you just pasted the formula (each formula with respect to its' own cell). **Keep the absolute referencing**. Finally you drag this down until you've reached the last item in the data (so you vectors are in length of `ROWS(materials)*COLUMNS(materials)`).

Now you just add a Pivot table on this vectors, and filter out the blank cells.

[image: Summing by item]

Tell me if it solved the problem ;)

P.S. Also if you want me to explain a little more about this, write me in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that A2:E4 contains the data, and A9:A13 contains the ingredients for which to return a count, enter the following formula in B9, confirm with CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER, and copy down:

```
=SUM(IF(RIGHT($B$2:$E$4,LEN(A9))=A9,LEFT($B$2:$E$4,FIND(" ",$B$2:$E$4)-1)+0))
```

Adjust the ranges accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

here is what i can do..

```
=SUM(IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(G6,$B$2:$E$4),0)>0,VALUE(LEFT($B$2:$E$4,SEARCH(CHAR(32),$B$2:$E$4)-1)),0))
```

[image]

(p/s: i change garlic for pasta to 5, i love garlic)